# How to assign private IP only to EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Below is the cloudformation code creating EC2 instance in **public subnet**, taken from [here](https://github.com/shamhub/docker-jenkins/blob/bd9ba043092d5cafd8c8f8bdd691430a512b360e/stack.json#L19):

```
"EC2Instance":{ "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance", "Properties":{ "ImageId": "ami-05958d7635caa4d04", "InstanceType": "t2.micro", "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId"}, "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName"}, "SecurityGroupIds": [ { "Ref": "EC2InstanceSecurityGroup"} ], "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref" : "EC2InstanceProfile"}, "UserData":{ "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ "#!/bin/bash\n", "echo ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref": "EcsCluster" }, " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n", "groupadd -g 1000 jenkins\n", "useradd -u 1000 -g jenkins jenkins\n", "mkdir -p /ecs/jenkins_home\n", "chown -R jenkins:jenkins /ecs/jenkins_home\n" ] ] } }, "Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-instance" ] ]} }] } },
```

---

By default, public IP is getting assigned to EC2 instance:

How to make EC2 instance assign private IP only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is easy.

set `AssociatePublicIpAddress` to `false`.

```
"Ec2Instance" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" : {
    "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ]},
    "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
    "NetworkInterfaces": [ {
      "AssociatePublicIpAddress": false,
      "DeviceIndex": "0",
      "GroupSet": [{ "Ref" : "myVPCEC2SecurityGroup" }],
      "SubnetId": { "Ref" : "PublicSubnet" }
    } ]
  }
}
```

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html

Comment: is what you were looking for?

Comment: updated the answer. initially i didnt read the question properly ;)

Comment: Will test tomorrow morning, and confirm you

Comment: For using `NetworkInterfaces` property, to add `SubnetId` & `AssociatePublicIpAddress`, Do I need to use `Replacement`, because documentation says: "If you use this property to point to a network interface, you must terminate the original interface before attaching a new one to allow the update of the instance to succeed."

Comment: If you are changing the subnetId, AssociatePublicIpAddress properties of the network interface according to this documentation, it should not cause any interruption. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-network-iface-embedded.html

Comment: I did this test, it replaced my instance